Why does Gather behaves this way?
I wrote the following:
Z = {{1, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {2, 4}};
Gather[Z, IntersectingQ[#1, #2] &]

This yields:
{{{1, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}}, {{2, 4}}}

Ie: They are collected into two classes, why is {2,4} not in the same class as the others since {2,4}, {4,1} and {3,2} have non-empty intersection?

#1 is {1,3} at the begging. Gathering second and third element because there is an intersection. But there is no intersection with the fourth element so that element is gathered into another group.

See this post: "The issue with using one Gather command is that it seems to assume that the test function that goes in the second slot is transitive."

Agree with @JasonB. that transitivity is the issue. To get a better view of the structure of your list Z, you can plot a connectivity graph: G = AdjacencyGraph[Outer[Boole@*IntersectingQ, Z, Z, 1], VertexLabels -> Automatic] and then look for connected components with ConnectedComponents[G].

If you want transitive closure, see this question.
